# Magento account controller rewrite set custom phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides

I need to overwrite Account Controller and set another phtml templates for it.

I overwrites Account Controller .It working as I hope.but problem is i can't set my custom phtml template to it.

here is my config xml routing part

```
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <customaccount>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Company_Customaccount</module>
                    <frontName>customaccount</frontName>
                </args>
              </customaccount>

             <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                    <customaccount before="Mage_Customer">Company_Customaccount</customaccount>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>


        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <customaccount>
                    <file>Customaccount.xml</file>
                </customaccount>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
```

My account controller

```
<?php
require_once 'Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php';
class Company_Customaccount_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{

 public function indexAction(){

$this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');


        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('caacount/caccount.phtml')
        );
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('My Account'));
        $this->renderLayout();




    } 



}
```

I can't find what is issue.
when i  put die() into account controller.it show.it means it overwritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change code

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('caacount/caccount.phtml')
        );
```

to:

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/account_dashboard')->setTemplate('caacount/caccount.phtml')
        );
```

Comment: no it not work.it goes to original phtml file

Comment: Are you trying to set custom template for dashboard?

Comment: yes i need to set custom template

Comment: Update code check it.